# Why is angular4 component variable destroyed

Tags: angular

I am making pagination component. This is code:

```
import {Component,OnInit,Input,Output,EventEmitter,OnChanges} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector:"pagination",
    templateUrl:"pagination.component.html"
})
export class Pagination implements OnChanges{

    @Input()
    numOfPages:number;

    @Output()
    onPageClicked:EventEmitter<number>=new EventEmitter<number>();

    pages:number[];

    constructor(){
        var a=<any>Array(this.numOfPages).keys();   
       this.pages= a;
    }
    ngOnChanges(){
        debugger;
        var a=<any>Array(this.numOfPages).keys();
         this.pages= a;
    }
    onSomePageClicked(page){

          this.onPageClicked.emit(page);
    }

}
```

Everything works at beggining. Clicking on page emits event also. However when event is emmited for some reason `this.pages` variable is empty array. At beggining is 7 elements array because I call this component like this:

```
<pagination [numOfPages]="7" (onPageClicked)="onPageItemClicked($event)"></pagination>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot by using `any` and ignoring TypeScript errors.

If you try to compile the lines

```
var a = Array(this.numOfPages).keys();   
this.pages= a;
```

you'll get an error saying "Initializer type IterableIterator is not assignable to variable type number[]".

So TypeScript tells you that you're doing something wrong, and you pretend it's incorrect by adding `<any>`. It is correct. `Array(this.numOfPages).keys()` does not return an array. So just fix the code and create a real array of numbers:

```
private pageArray(size: number): Array<number> {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result.push(i + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9G5ReCWGmF6jywMnB5nW?p=preview.